# What is the critical current density of indium tin oxide ITO?

Tags: current

What is the critical current density of indium tin oxide ITO?

Comment: I don't think it has one; ITO isn't a superconductor is it?

Comment: Also, what *are* you trying to do? You keep asking questions about current density an utterly absurd amounts of charge, and I'm very curious why you're asking these questions.

Comment: @Hearth According to [this](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1203/1203.4644.pdf) it is, at 5 K or so.

Comment: @The Photon Thanks!

Comment: @Albert What did I ever do to warrant being ignored? I'm trying to help, but I can't help without knowing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course Jc will depend on the temperature and magnetic field.

This paper...

> Aliev, A. E., de Andrade, M. J., & Salamon, M. B. (2016). Paramagnetic
> Meissner Effect in Electrochemically Doped Indium-Tin Oxide Films.
> Journal of Superconductivity and Novel Magnetism, 29(7), 1793–1803.
> doi:10.1007/s10948-016-3501-7

...suggests it's around 20 million to 40 million A/m^2 at liquid helium temperatures.

[image]